# Help identifying 6-pin SMD components with 46 L code

Tags: identification, surface-mount, latching

I am looking for the SMD below. Code "46" and vertical "L".

It is used in a latch circuit and could be a NAND gate or equivalent, something like a flip-flop circuit.

Here is the link to a [circuit using this IC](https://www.pololu.com/product/2808).

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome.  do you have any more information?  How old is the equipment and where was it made?  Could you post a picture of any of the surrounding circuitry?  An image this close up doesn't have very many clues.

Comment: I just edited the post with a link to Pololu circuit

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a MBT3946 NPN-PNP transistor pair. [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/mbt3946dw1t1-d.pdf).

[image]

The other transistors on that board appear to be: **MUN2211** (8A) transistor with input resistors [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/dtc114e-d.pdf).  (Found pretty easily through [Ultimate SMD Database](https://smd.yooneed.one/))

You can confirm by tracing out portions of [Pololu board](https://www.pololu.com/product/2808) per your link, and comparing with their input circuit descriptions, in particular `CTRL` to base of an NPN through 4K7 resistor.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! I didn't know  Ultimate DMS Database !

My initial goal was to replace the MUN2211 by BC846 & resistors.

For the MBT3946 I was in the fog ! Thank you !